# Ampersand in Glossary- how to escape it?

Tags: glossaries, ampersand

I have a specific problem with the use of "&" in the glossary. In my text, I have:

```
\gls{CUT\&RUN}
```

to define it as a glossary item. And I try to write the new glossary item description in my main document as so:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[toc,nopostdot,nogroupskip,style=super,nonumberlist,automake]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{CUT\&RUN}{name={CUT\&RUN}, text={CUT\&RUN}, description={Cleavage Under Targets and Release Using Nuclease}}
```

When I put the `\` in front of all ampersands, I get 46 errors all of a sudden- I am not sure how to make this work!

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, as is custom here, please provide a full but minimal document that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add code to even test your problem, and our choice of code may differ from yours

Comment: Thanks for the heads up- I tried to add this now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[toc,nopostdot,nogroupskip,style=super,nonumberlist,automake]{glossa\
ries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{CUT-AND-RUN}{name={CUT\&RUN}, text={CUT\&RUN},
  description={Cleavage Under Targets and Release Using Nuclease}}

\begin{document}
\gls{CUT-AND-RUN}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, this works perfectly! Thanks for this beautiful solution and for the quick reply!

Comment: @bsbt, you are welcome!